# How to get around property does not exist on 'Object'

Tags: object, typescript

I'm new to Typescript, and not sure how to word this question.

I need to access two "possible" properties on an object that is passed in the constructor. I know im missing some checks to see if they are defined, but Typescript is throwing me a "Property does not exist on 'Object'" message. The message appears on the **selector** and **template** returns.

```
class View {
    public options:Object = {};

   constructor(options:Object) {
       this.options = options;
   }

   selector ():string {
       return this.options.selector;
   }   

   template ():string {
       return this.options.template;
   }   

   render ():void {

   }   
}
```

I'm sure its fairly simple, but Typescript is new to me.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you use the `any` type instead of `Object`, you can access any property without compile errors.

However, I would advise to create an interface that marks the possible properties for that object:

```
interface Options {
  selector?: string
  template?: string
}
```

Since all of the fields use `?:`, it means that they might or might not be there. So this works:

```
function doStuff(o: Options) {
  //...
}

doStuff({}) // empty object
doStuff({ selector: "foo" }) // just one of the possible properties
doStuff({ selector: "foo", template: "bar" }) // all props
```

If something comes from javascript, you can do something like this:

```
import isObject from 'lodash/isObject'

const myOptions: Options = isObject(somethingFromJS) // if an object
    ? (somethingFromJS as Options) // cast it
    : {} // else create an empty object

doStuff(myOptions) // this works now
```

Of course this solution only works as expected if you are only unsure about the presence of a property not of it's type.

Comment: Hi, good answer. Why you didn't use a class instead of a interface?

Comment: @RafaelReyes Interfaces will have no trace in the generated javascript, it's purely type information (as it should be in this case).

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want to change the type or create an interface, you can also use this syntax to access unknown properties:

```
selector ():string {
    return this.options["selector"];
}   

template ():string {
    return this.options["template"];
}
```

Comment: This works but seems to truly undermine TypeScript's typing

Comment: This is even more tricky when you do a for (let item of items) and item.x is not a property of object and you can't seem to cast it.