# Angular2 custom filter giving error Property status does not exist on type Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have ran into a weird issue. I am getting error

> Property "status" does not exist on type "Object"

The filter is working sometimes and sometimes its giving the above error, eventough the code is untouched.I am using angular CLI and while building the application the same error is raising. Please help.

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterTablePipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {
if (!items || !filter) {
        return items;
    }
return items.filter(item => item.status.indexOf(filter.status)!== -1)
}
}
```

Part of my **filter-table.component.ts**

```
filterargs = {
'status': ''
};

changed(e) {
this.filterVal = e.value;
this.filterargs = {
    'status': this.filterVal
};
if (this.filterVal == 'all') {
    this.filterargs = {
        'status': ''
    };
  }
 }
```

**filtertable.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data | filterPipe:filterargs ;let i = index">
        <td>
            <div class="squaredThree">
                <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="filter{{i}}" name="check" [(ngModel)]='item.selected' (click)='getSelection(item)' />
                <label for="filter{{i}}"></label>
            </div>
            {{item.clcode}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cccode}}</td>
        <td>{{item.invoices}}</td>
        <td>{{item.shipments}}</td>

        <td>{{item.maudits}}</td>
        <td>{{item.auditdl | date}}</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style='width:90%'>{{item.assignee}}</td>
                    <td style='width:7%'>
                        <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                            <a dropdownToggle type="button" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                <span class="custom-caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607979/how-to-get-around-property-does-not-exist-on-object

Comment: Guessing `filter.status` is a `string` rather than an `Object` try changing your `filter:Object` to `:any`

Comment: Thanks it was the issue. Solved my headache thank you guys