# `RxJS` throws error on subcribe when do request

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular5

I am making a request using observable. and trying to subcribe the value. But getting error on typescript. any on help me?

I like to do this:

```
public getCountry(lat,lan):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false').subscribe(data => {
        return this.genertedData(data);
    } );
}
```

But getting error as follows:

[image: Observable Error]

**UPDATES**

```
 public getCountry(lat,lan):Observable<any>{

        return this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false').map( data => {

            data.results.map( array => {
                let details = array.address_components.find( obj => obj.types.includes("country") );
                this.countryDetails.countryLongName = details.long_name;
                this.countryDetails.countryShortName = details.short_name;
            })

            return this.countryDetails;
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your return type states `Observable<any>`, where as you actually return whatever `this.genertedData(data)` returns (Hint: Sounds like a typo in your function. Guess it should be called `generatedData` ?).

Best practice would be to move the http call into a service and `subscribe` to its returned `Observable` within your component.

So to speak:

```
// => service.ts
public getCountryObservable(lat,lan):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false');
}
```

Your component would look something like:

```
// => component.ts
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(public yourService: YourService) {}
  getCountry(lat, lan): whateverDataTypeYourGeneratedDataReturns {
    this.yourService.getCountryObservable(lat, lan).subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = this.generatedData(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `getCountryObservable` how to map the details? I require to add the filter

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions inside a single post.
Also, it totally depends on what your actual data returned by the server looks like. I suggest you create a new question with more details. It sounds like you're trying to accomplish something fairly basic.

Comment: the problem is the object which comes from backend is unknow. but getting the declaration issue as mentioned.  that's what i added the question. please see my edited update. I am getting underline at `data.results` how can i handle this?

Comment: `Property 'results'  does not exist on type 'Object'` - this is what the error

Comment: If you *really* do not know what the object you receive from the backend looks like (which sounds like you got worse problems, really) you may use the `any` type instead of `Object` (as my answer already states). Better option would be to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607979/how-to-get-around-property-does-not-exist-on-object

Comment: agree. But finding dificult to integrate. can you update your answer? ( please don't mind )

Comment: Again, the answer is "up to date" already. Simply change your return type from `Observable<Object>` to `Observable<any>` for your `getCountry` method.

Comment: still getting the same issue after updating like `public getCountry(lat,lan):Observable<any>{` - help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169997/discussion-between-philipp-meissner-and-user2024080).

Answer (score 1):

Since the return type of the function is `Observable<any>`, I guess it should just return `this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false')`

Comment: updating this line `return this.http.get(this.googleApi+lat+','+lan+'&sensor=false').map((data:any) =>` helped me. thanks for your time!!