# How to update the Strapi GraphQL cache, after creating new data?

Tags: vue.js, apollo, apollo-client, strapi, vue-apollo

## How to update the cache, after creating new data?

### Error message from Apollo

**Store error:** the application attempted to write an object with no provided id but the store already contains an id of UsersPermissionsUser:1 for this object. The selectionSet that was trying to be written is:

```js
{
  "kind": "Field",
  "name": { "kind": "Name", "value": "user" },
  "arguments": [],
  "directives": [],
  "selectionSet": {
    "kind": "SelectionSet",
    "selections": [
      { "kind": "Field", "name": { "kind": "Name", "value": "username" }, "arguments": [], "directives": [] },

      { "kind": "Field", "name": { "kind": "Name", "value": "__typename" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Nativescript-vue Front-end Details

[image]

1- **Watch Book Mobile app in action** on YouTube: https://youtu.be/sBM-ErjXWuw

2- **Watch Question video for details** on YouTube: https://youtu.be/wqvrcBRQpZg

**{N}**-vue  **AddBook.vue file**

```js
apolloClient
        .mutate({
          // Query
          mutation: mutations.CREATE_BOOK,
          // Parameters
          variables: {
            name: this.book.name,
            year: this.book.year,
          },
           // HOW TO UPDATE
          update: (store, { data }) => {
            console.log("data   ::::>> ", data.createBook.book);
            const bookQuery = {
              query: queries.ALL_BOOKS,
            };
// TypeScript detail: instead of creating an interface
// I used any type access books property without compile errors.
            const bookData:any = store.readQuery(bookQuery);
            console.log('bookData :>> ', bookData);
// I pin-pointed data objects
// Instead of push(createBook) I've pushed data.createBook.book
            bookData.books.push(data.createBook.book);
            store.writeQuery({ ...bookQuery, data: bookData })
          },
        })
        .then((data) => {
          // I can even see ID in Result
          console.log("new data.data id  ::::: :>> ", data.data.createBook.book.id);
          this.$navigateTo(App);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Error
          console.error(error);
        });
```

#### What are these `"Book:9": {` lines in the cache?

console.log store  turns out:

```
"Book:9": {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Hadi",
        "year": "255",
        "__typename": "Book"
      },
      "$ROOT_MUTATION.createBook({\"input\":{\"data\":{\"name\":\"Hadi\",\"year\":\"255\"}}})": {
```

You can see all [front-end GitHub repo here](https://github.com/kaanguru/mutate-question/tree/solution)

- [Download Android apk file](https://sendgb.com/RTEzdXk9ync)

Our goal is to update the cache. *Add Book Method* is in here:
https://github.com/kaanguru/mutate-question/blob/c199f8dcc8e80e83abdbcde4811770b766befcb5/nativescript-vue/app/components/AddBook.vue#L39

---

#### Back-end details

However, this is a frontend question a running Strapi GraphQL Server is here: https://polar-badlands-01357.herokuapp.com/admin/

[GraphQL Playground](https://polar-badlands-01357.herokuapp.com/graphql)

**USER:** admin

**PASSWORD:** passw123

You can see [GraphQL documentation](https://polar-badlands-01357.herokuapp.com/documentation/v1.0.0)

I have so much simple Strapi GrapQL Scheme:

[image: simple Strapi GrapQL Scheme]

If you want to test it using postman or insomnia you can use;

- POST GraphQL Query URL: https://polar-badlands-01357.herokuapp.com/graphql
- Bearer Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTkwODI3MzE0LCJleHAiOjE1OTM0MTkzMTR9.WIK-f4dkwVAyIlP20v1PFoflpwGmRYgRrsQiRFgGdqg

---

**NOTE:** Don't get confused with `$navigateTo()` it's just a custom method of nativescript-vue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It turns out;

*all code was correct* accept `bookData.push(createBook);`

```js
          // HOW TO UPDATE
          update: (store, { data }) => {
            console.log("data   ::::>> ", data.createBook.book);
            const bookQuery = {
              query: queries.ALL_BOOKS,
            };
// TypeScript detail: instead of creating an interface
// I used any type access books property without compile errors.
            const bookData:any = store.readQuery(bookQuery);
            console.log('bookData :>> ', bookData);
// I pin-pointed data objects
// Instead of push(createBook) I've pushed data.createBook.book
            bookData.books.push(data.createBook.book);
            store.writeQuery({ ...bookQuery, data: bookData })
          },
        })
```

### Typescipt was helping

The point is; I shouldn't trust TypeScript errors, or at least I should read more about what it really says.

Typescript just asked me to be more specific while saying: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

TypeScript was trying to tell me I need to be more specific while calling ROOT_MUTATION data. It said: `Cannot find name 'createBook'` But again I ignored it.

---

### Solution Github Branch

https://github.com/kaanguru/mutate-question/tree/solution

#### Sources

[how to update cache](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-the-apollo-clients-cache-after-a-mutation-79a0df79b840/)

[Create interface for object Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36608015/11993949)